# Is "$\mathbb{E}(T_n|X)\rightarrow 0 $ a.s." equivalent to a statement that does not involve the Radon–Nikodym derivative as a black box?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Let $\{T_n\}_n$ be a sequence of random variables, and let $X$ be another random variable.

Each $\mathbb{E}(T_n|X)$ is a random variable, therefore the statement "$\mathbb{E}(T_n|X)\rightarrow 0$ almost surely" makes sense in the sense of almost sure convergence of random variables.

What makes this difficult to unpack is that almost sure convergence is phrased in terms of individual $\omega$'s in the probability space, but the definition of $\mathbb{E}(T_n|X)$ is via the existence of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, and so is non-constructive...

The question is whether you can have an equivalent definition of this statement that does not use the Radon-Nikodym derivative as a black box. For example, is it equivalent to the statement: "for every measurable set $U$ in the co-domain of $X$, the mean of $T_n$ over $X^{-1}(U)$ converges to $0$"?

Comment: At the level of logic, note that it's only the *existence* of the conditional expectation that relies on the Radon-Nikodym theorem; the definition itself does not.  You should be able to formulate, and perhaps prove, a statement like "every conditional expectation of $T_n$ given $X$ converges a.s. to 0", without any reference to Radon-Nikodym.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking: Is the statement "$E(T_n|X)\to0$ almost surely [a.s.]" equivalent to the statement "for every measurable set $U$ in the co-domain of $X$, the mean of $T_n$ over $X^{-1}(U)$ converges to $0$"?

The answer is no in general. First here, to talk about the mean of $T_n$ over $X^{-1}(U)$, you need to assume that $P(X^{-1}(U))>0$. Taking this into account, we can restate your question as follows: Are the following two statements equivalent:

(i) $Y_n\to0$ a.s.

(ii) $EY_n\,1_{X\in U}\to0$ for all measurable sets $U$ in the co-domain of $X$,

where $Y_n:=E(T_n|X)$. Neither one of the implications (i)$\implies$(ii) or (ii)$\implies$(i) holds in general.

Indeed, let $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and then let $T_n:=nX1_{X<1/n}$, so that $Y_n=T_n$ and, for $U=[0,1]$, $EY_n\,1_{X\in U}=ET_n=1\not\to0$, whereas $Y_n=T_n\to0$ a.s. So, the implication (i)$\implies$(ii) fails to hold.

On the other hand, let again $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, and then let $T_n:=X1_{X\in\delta_n}$, where $\delta_1,\delta_2,\dots$ are subintervals of $[0,1]$ such that  $T_n\to0$ in probability but not a.s. Then again $Y_n=T_n$ and hence (i) fails to hold, whereas (ii) holds by dominated convergence. So, the implication (ii)$\implies$(i) fails to hold.

Comment: Mmm, you're right of course. Can you see a different way of unpacking $E(T_n|X)\rightarrow 0$ a.s. constructively that would work?

Comment: @AndrewNC : I'd surprised if such unpacking is possible. Also, it is unclear what you mean by "does not use the Radon-Nikodym derivative as a black box".